# How to access cell value from pivot table from excel sheet using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to access cell value from pivot table from excel sheet using Apache POI?
I tried using XSSFPivotTable.getPivotTables, but not able to access cell value.
Book1.xlsx is the excel workbook which has a pivot table on sheet Sheet1.

`FileInoutStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(Book1.xlsx));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
XSSFPivotTable pt = sh.getPivotTables().get(0);`

Not able to access the cells in pt pivot table ahead of this.

Comment: Hi.
Please add a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can have a better look at what youre trying to do and where the problem could be.

Comment: @FabianSchöner Added MCVE.

Comment: Did you got the answer?

Comment: Did you got solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Below a custom way to access to pivot table header and data , im not sure but i couldnt find a way to access to the data via library , searching on line i read something about, which says it is not supported yet .

Lets see what i did :

Input file :

[image]

Tranform letters in numbers for columns:

```
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
            {
                int index =1;
                for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch) {
                    put(String.valueOf(ch), index); 
                    index++;
                }
            }
    };
```

Getting table object

```
java.util.List<XSSFPivotTable> l = sh.getPivotTables();
```

**Below the code which will make a trick for the result**

XML Debug view :

```
<xml-fragment name="PivotTable7" cacheId="24" applyNumberFormats="0" applyBorderFormats="0" applyFontFormats="0" applyPatternFormats="0" applyAlignmentFormats="0" applyWidthHeightFormats="1" dataCaption="Values" updatedVersion="6" minRefreshableVersion="3" useAutoFormatting="1" itemPrintTitles="1" createdVersion="6" indent="0" outline="1" outlineData="1" multipleFieldFilters="0" xmlns:main="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <main:location ref="F6:G7" firstHeaderRow="0" firstDataRow="1" firstDataCol="0"/>
  <main:pivotFields count="2">
    <main:pivotField dataField="1" subtotalTop="0" showAll="0">
      <main:items count="2">
        <main:item x="0"/>
        <main:item t="default"/>
      </main:items>
    </main:pivotField>
    <main:pivotField dataField="1" subtotalTop="0" showAll="0"/>
  </main:pivotFields>
  <main:rowItems count="1">
    <main:i/>
  </main:rowItems>
  <main:colFields count="1">
    <main:field x="-2"/>
  </main:colFields>
  <main:colItems count="2">
    <main:i>
      <main:x/>
    </main:i>
    <main:i i="1">
      <main:x v="1"/>
    </main:i>
  </main:colItems>
  <main:dataFields count="2">
    <main:dataField name="A" fld="0" baseField="0" baseItem="1"/>
    <main:dataField name="B" fld="1" baseField="0" baseItem="1"/>
  </main:dataFields>
  <main:pivotTableStyleInfo name="PivotStyleLight16" showRowHeaders="1" showColHeaders="1" showRowStripes="0" showColStripes="0" showLastColumn="1"/>
  <main:extLst>
    <main:ext uri="{962EF5D1-5CA2-4c93-8EF4-DBF5C05439D2}" xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main">
      <x14:pivotTableDefinition hideValuesRow="1" xmlns:xm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2006/main"/>
    </main:ext>
    <main:ext uri="{747A6164-185A-40DC-8AA5-F01512510D54}" xmlns:xpdl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/pivotdefaultlayout">
      <xpdl:pivotTableDefinition16 SubtotalsOnTopDefault="0"/>
    </main:ext>
  </main:extLst>
</xml-fragment>
```

Looking at **ref="F6:G7"** i know the range which will make the trick

```
 String range = l.get(0).getCTPivotTableDefinition().getLocation().getRef(); //F6:G7 rows/cols reference - case of our sheet

            //determinate range of table
            int firstcol = map.get(range.substring(0, 1));
            int firstrow = Integer.parseInt(range.substring(1, 2));
            int lastcol = map.get(range.substring(3, 4));
            int lastrow = Integer.parseInt(range.substring(4, 5));
```

The complete code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //tranform letters in numbers for columns
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
            {
                int index =1;
                for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch) {
                    put(String.valueOf(ch), index); 
                    index++;
                }
            }
    };
    try {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Desktop\\ook.xlsx"));

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sh.iterator();
        ArrayList columndata = new ArrayList<>();

        java.util.List<XSSFPivotTable> l = sh.getPivotTables();

        String range = l.get(0).getCTPivotTableDefinition().getLocation().getRef(); //F6:G7 rows/cols reference - case of our sheet

        //determinate range of table
        int firstcol = map.get(range.substring(0, 1));
        int firstrow = Integer.parseInt(range.substring(1, 2));
        int lastcol = map.get(range.substring(3, 4));
        int lastrow = Integer.parseInt(range.substring(4, 5));

while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    if(checkrightrowcol(row.getRowNum()+1, firstrow, lastrow)){
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

        if(checkrightrowcol(cell.getColumnIndex()+1,firstcol,lastcol)){    

           switch(cell.getCellType()){
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: // numeric value 
                System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: // String Value 
                System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                break;

                //..add more 
                }
            }
           }
        }
    }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Explanation of **checkrightrowcol**

```
public static boolean checkrightrowcol(int n , int start, int end){

        while (start!=end){
            if(n == start || n == end)
                return true;
            start++;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If it returns true im in the table data , in the main i use "+1" because rows and columns indexes start from "0"

Result :

[image]

Comment: I tried the above code, but facing a weird issue. Able to get correct range say K6:N21 if the pivot is created manual in excel, but if pivot is created programmatically then getting range as K6:L7. And just for records, the pivot table is created correct with program.

Comment: I see man , im not sure , but it could be a limit of the library