# Is there any way we can read Data from created Pivot Table using java code?

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-pivot

I am creating pivot table using poi and save it into another sheet but after that i want to read the data of recently created pivot table but somehow i could't get it
For creating Pivot i am using:

```
    File file = new File(filepath);
    try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);)

    {

        XSSFWorkbook testData = null;
        testData = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet testDataSheet = testData.getSheet(sheetname);
        XSSFSheet sheet2 = testData.createSheet("pivot");
        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet2.createPivotTable(new AreaReference(range, null), new CellReference("A1"), testDataSheet);

        pivotTable.addRowLabel(rownum);
        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(dataConsolidateFunction, value);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(pivotsheetpath);
        testData.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        inputStream.close();
        testData.close();

    }

}
```

getting data from excel:

```
    String[][] data = null;
    File file = new File(filePath);

    try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);)
    {

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        XSSFWorkbook testData = null;
        String fileExtensionName = FilenameUtils.getExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtensionName.equals("xlsx"))
            testData = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

        XSSFSheet testDataSheet = testData.getSheet(sheetName);
        row = testDataSheet.getLastRowNum() - testDataSheet.getFirstRowNum();
        column = testDataSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum() - testDataSheet.getRow(0).getFirstCellNum();
        data = new String[row + 1][column];

        for (Row rows : testDataSheet)
            for (Cell cell : rows)
                data[rows.getRowNum()][cell.getColumnIndex()] = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
        testData.close();
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940804/how-to-access-cell-value-from-pivot-table-from-excel-sheet-using-apache-poi .  https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFPivotTable.html

Comment: @AdiOhana i have tried using that but it is not working in my case

Comment: can you share some of your code?

Comment: @AdiOhana yes sure you can find it now